# Rails generate select with both options and option groups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

Is it possible to generate select like:

```
<select>
  <option value>Some nill value label</option>
  <option value="1">Option one</option>
  <optgroup label="Option Group 1" class="css-class-for-option-group-1">
    <option value="1:1">Option one in group 1</option>
    <option value="1:2">Option two in group 1</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Option Group 2" class="css-class-for-option-group-2">
    <option value="2:1">Option one in group 2</option>
    <option value="2:2">Option two in group 2</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

I tried to use the `grouped_options_for_select`, but I failed to find I way to pass both option and groups to it. Is there any way to achieve this? I am open to suggestions using SimpleForm as well.

Thanks!

Comment: What does the data look like that you want to render options for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is hard to answer precisely without knowing what the data looks like, but I'm going to guess that you have something like this:

```
@grouped_options = [
  ["Some nil value label"],
  ["Option one", "1"],
  ["Option Group 1",
    [
      ["Option one in group 1", "1:1"],
      ["Option two in group 1", "1:2"],
    ]
  ],
  ["Option Group 2",
    [
      ["Option one in group 2", "2:1"],
      ["Option two in group 2", "2:2"],
    ]
  ],
]
```

With that, you have a couple options. In plain ERB, you can do it like this:

```erb
<%= select "thing", "some_attr" do %>
  <% @grouped_options.each do |label, value_or_options| %>
    <% if Array === value_or_options %>
      <%= tag.optgroup options_for_select(value_or_options), label: label %>
    <% else %>
      <%= tag.option label, value: value_or_options %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Personally, though, I would write a helper. The [`Enumerable#chunk`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) method splits an array into runs of values that return the same thing for the given block, making it easy to separate the grouped from the non-grouped items so we can use `grouped_options_for_select` and `options_for_select`, respectively:

```
def ungrouped_and_grouped_options_for_select(choices, selected_key = nil)
  capture do
    choices
      .chunk {|_, choice_or_group| Array === choice_or_group }
      .each do |is_group, choices_or_grouped_choices|
        if is_group
          concat grouped_options_for_select(choices_or_grouped_choices, selected_key)
        else
          concat options_for_select(choices_or_grouped_choices, selected_key)
        end
      end
  end
end
```

You could then use it this:

```erb
<%= select "thing", "some_attr" do %>
  <%= ungrouped_and_grouped_options_for_select(@grouped_options) %>
<% end %>
```

You can see both of these approaches in action on repl.it: https://repl.it/@jrunning/UnacceptablePlaintiveServer (see `views/tests/index.html.erb`, `controllers/tests_controller.rb`, and `helpers/application_helper.rb`).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the data is formatted as described by Jordan, you could also combine both 'select options' methods (`options_for_select` and `grouped_options_for_select`) by summing their return, like so:

```
<%= f.select :selected_ids, options_for_select([['Option 1', 1]]) + grouped_options_for_select([['Option Group 1', ['group1opt1', 11], ['group1opt2', 12]], ['Option Group 2', ['group2opt1', 21], ['group2opt2', 22]]]), {}, { class: 'class' } %>
```